# How to square a long board

Tags: technique, table-saw, jig

I have a 10in craftsman table saw with the fence. How would I square up the sides of a 1x6x4ft board? Would i need jig of some kind. Or would using circular with a straight edge be better.  Mainly looking for proper technique using a table saw.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Unless you already have a straight edge on your board, your fence will just replicate the errors of one edge to the other.  What you need is a straight edge jig. It's fairly easy to build.  Here's an example from the Wood Magazine.

[image: Straight Edge Jib]

There's also [many videos on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=straight+edge+jig+table+saw+).

Answer (score 1):

A jointer if you have one is a better way of squaring the edge of the board.

Set the board with the face you already jointed to the fence of the jointer and make a pass.

You can square up the other edge with the table saw.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest procedure is to use a fence and a feather. It looks like this:

[image]

You can either buy them or make them. Use scrap wood to adjust the feather and the fence until they are perfectly straight.

Use a carpenter's square to determine whether each of your four corners is square.

Comment: This doesn't really help if the fence-side of the board isn't flat/true to begin with.